# CSS Images in EmberJS addons

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'd like to know the idiomatic way to reference css images (images linked in css through `url(...)` ) from within an Ember addon.

Ostensibly the addon `public/` folder will get merged with `dist/` in the final build and the css files will be merged with `vendor.css`

How can images therefore be linked i.e. if I have an image in `/my-addon/public/images/icon.png` how should I reference it in my CSS file? I've tried `url(/my-addon/images/icon.png)` and it doesn't respect the `rootURL` setting (only works if `rootUrl = '/'`).

The only thing that seems to work is `url(../my-addon/images/icon.png)` but I've never heard mention that images should be linked with relative paths in this way.

Is there an established way to reference image assets from within addon css?

I've tried everything mentioned above but the only thing that works is relative paths. Am I correct to do so?

Comment: things get a little more clear if you declare support for certain times of build systems -- for example, in embroider/webpack, importing an image in to a javascript file gives the publish-time URL, which can be thrown on img.src, or however the URL wants to be used.

Comment: This is a very tantalizing clue @NullVoxPopuli. Is this different from the default configuration?

Comment: yeah, default configuration isn't for embroider -- the way your URLs need to be depends on your intended audience, etc